# How can I check for inclusion of a datetime in a range in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Using Ruby's [`Range#include?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Range/include%3F) with a datetime range throws an exception:

```
> (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).include?(Time.zone.now)
TypeError: can't iterate from ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

While using Rails' [`Range#overlaps?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Range/overlaps%3F) works:

```
> (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).overlaps?(Time.zone.now..Time.zone.now)
=> true
```

I dislike the fact that I have to create a single-element range to check for inclusion using `overlaps?` Is there a way to use `include?` with a datetime range in Rails?

Comment: Do you need to have the zone?

Comment: @brianslattery Not necessarily, this is to illustrate as best as possible the problem I encounter. The objects I am manipulating are of type `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, hence the `.zone`. You will note that without the zone, the aforementioned code still throws the following exception: `TypeError: can't iterate from Time`.

Answer (score 3):

Aha!

How is this?

```
Time.zone.now.between?(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

Result:

```
2.3.0 :001 > Time.zone.now.between?(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,Time.zone.tomorrow.end_of_day)
 => true 
2.3.0 :002 > Time.zone.tomorrow.between?(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
 => false 
2.3.0 :003 > Time.zone.yesterday.between?(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F

Comment: This works and could be a solution to my problem but it does not exactly answer my question: why doesn't `Range::include?` work with datetimes? Since I am manipulating ranges, accordingly to your idea I would have to do `Time.zone.now.between?((Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).begin, (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).end)`. It works but kinda defeats the purpose of using ranges.